# How can I reserve bandwidth on network without router access?

Tags: networking, router, bandwidth, qos

I am in an apartment complex with a shared connection, that I think is probably being split up with a switch among all of the apartments, so a lousy internet service gets even worse and I'm fairly sure there are a couple of heavy net users that kill almost all traffic. I am hard-lined in via Ethernet, so it's not due to wireless lag.

I want to know if there is a way to tell the router to allocate a set amount of bandwidth to my computer so that even when someone is killing it they can't kill it for me as well.

I know that if I have access to the router I can possibly tweak the QoS settings, or external software/hardware if the router didn't have Qos, but currently I don't have access to the router.

Would it be possible to just create a tunnel (wrong word, I know) to kind of reserve a particular amount of bandwidth and then operate normally within that amount?

Comment: How can I use up all my neighbor's bandwidth so they don't use up mine?

Answer (score 1):

To sum up the answer to your question, no. The router is a fuel intake valve on a car, it controls how much can be used at any given time, nothing on either end can change that only a modification to its settings can.